# Static text cutting off while exporting reports to pdf in Linux Deployments using Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

We have static text cutting while exporting reports to pdf in Linux Deployments. The values seems to be displayed correctly only the static text is cut off. Below is the screenshot for report pdf in Windows and Linux Deployments.

Any help or input would be really appreciated.

Report on Linux region
[Screenshot from Linux for report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VfFF.png)

Report in Windows
[Screenshot from Windows for report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1SH4.png)

```
<style name="Base" isDefault="true" fontSize="8"  pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

Code for Status field

```
 <staticText>
      <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="11" width="29" height="11" forecolor="#000000" uuid="33ebd0e4-a138-4a26-943e-a7c1b23fd5ed"/>
      <textElement>
           <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Status: ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="29" y="11" width="140" height="11" forecolor="#000000" uuid="465caf4d-66e7-412f-81f3-02349696cfc0"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{claimStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
```

Loss Description

```
<frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="33" width="473" height="11" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#000000" uuid="2fc22d18-89c7-4b7c-a583-ca4f7acd2344">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{lossDescription} != null && $P{lossDescription}.length() > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>                
                <staticText>                
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="69" height="11" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#000000" uuid="70d296f8-0869-4ecf-bf57-a6bdc50366de" backcolor="blue">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{lossDescription} != null && $P{lossDescription}.length() > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    
                    <textElement>                        
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Loss Description: ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="69" y="0" width="368" height="11" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#000000" uuid="7318184a-2d1a-4c75-aaf7-e5c2609e7d92">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{lossDescription} != null && $P{lossDescription}.length() > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>                   
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{lossDescription}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
```

Comment: It means that the engine can't use the font (the same that was used at Windows)

Comment: @AlexK - Thank you for your response. Shall I try other fonts you mean? I tried Arial in pdfFontName but it was not in Linux machine so I got an exception.

Comment: <style name="Base" isDefault="true" fontSize="8"  pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve it, we included the Arial font in jasper-font jar and changed the font from Helvetica to Arial in reports.

Once done, Reports started rendering fine in Linux and Windows region since Arial font TTF files were part of the war thru jasper-font jar.